# Prevent form postback on <asp:Button> using a jQuery confirmation dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, modal-dialog

I have an asp.net button with both onclick and onclientclick events.

```
<asp:Button  ID="ButtonSave" Text="Save" ToolTip="Save" CssClass="causesValidation button" OnClick="ButtonSave_Click" OnClientClick="myfunction();" runat="server"/>
```

As soon as I click the button, both the client side and server side events are being fired. I only want the server side event to run if the client-side function succeeds.

I tried the following:

```
function myfunction()
{
    // Show dialog
    $('#mydialog').dialog('open');


// on dialog confirmation return true, else false;
}

<asp:Button  ID="ButtonSave" Text="Save" ToolTip="Save" CssClass="causesValidation button" OnClick="ButtonSave_Click" OnClientClick="return myfunction();" runat="server"/>
```

Thank you

Comment: Well, it's the intention that both events are getting fired. If you dislike that, remove the event that you don't want to happen.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question- I have an asp.net button which will cause the form to validate and also has an onclick event. Now i want to do some javascript calculations before i submit the form. But i want to validate the form before i execute the onclientclick. What would be the best way?

Comment: to be more precise i am showing a dialog from the javascript function and the dialog has got two buttons ok and cancel. On OK click i want to submit the form. But i want the form validated before showing the dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
OnClientClick="myfunction();"
```

by

```
OnClientClick="return myfunction();"
```

Comment: Let me rephrase the question- I have an asp.net button which will cause the form to validate and also has an onclick event. Now i want to do some javascript calculations before i submit the form. But i want to validate the form before i execute the onclientclick. What would be the best way?

Comment: to be more precise i am showing a dialog from the javascript function and the dialog has got two buttons ok and cancel. On OK click i want to submit the form. But i want the form validated before showing the dialog.

Comment: @user1473171: Validate inside `myfunction` and return false in case any validation fails. wouldn't that work? How are you validating?

Comment: i tried to have a function validateControls() inside myFunction(); validateControls() tries to validate each control, but i have some custom validations on the server side which will be validated onClick.

Comment: I think i have to be more specific

Comment: I have an asp.net button, on button click i am currently doing some client side validations and once the client side validations have been resolved i am doing more validations on the server side. I have a contentpanel on the page where i display more validation messages from the server side validation. But the problem is i now want to show a dialog box when i click the button, But i want to validate both client and server side validations before i show the dialog. Once confirmed on the dialog i want the form to be saved. Hopefully i gave you all the details.

Comment: i mean contentholder control*

Comment: @user1473171: 2 things 1) Add all these details to your question so other people can try to help 2) This scenario is extremelly complex if you're asp.net using built in validators control. If you're using your  own validators or a client library you should need to do ajax calls to do server validations and according the result you show the pop up or not. Make sense?

Comment: yes it does. I realized that i will have to make an ajax call to do the server side validation.

Answer (score 0):

```
onclientclick=return function();
```

Comment: Let me rephrase the question- I have an asp.net button which will cause the form to validate and also has an onclick event. Now i want to do some javascript calculations before i submit the form. But i want to validate the form before i execute the onclientclick. What would be the best way?

Comment: to be more precise i am showing a dialog from the javascript function and the dialog has got two buttons ok and cancel. On OK click i want to submit the form. But i want the form validated before showing the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Change `OnClientClick="myfunction()"` to `OnClientClick="myfunction(); return false;"` and call `__doPostBack` function passing ButtonSave UniqueID as first argument value on dialog confirmation

Comment: this is causing the page to not validate

Comment: Let me rephrase the question- I have an asp.net button which will cause the form to validate and also has an onclick event. Now i want to do some javascript calculations before i submit the form. But i want to validate the form before i execute the onclientclick. What would be the best way?

Comment: to be more precise i am showing a dialog from the javascript function and the dialog has got two buttons ok and cancel. On OK click i want to submit the form. But i want the form validated before showing the dialog.

Comment: You can enforce client-side validation with ValidatorValidate function check `Page_IsValid` property value and show dialog or no depending on this property value. Follow this link for validation client-side API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx